# What is the difference in the meaning of these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

> We have to do homework.

and

> We are required to do homework.

Do they mean the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all contexts, both OP's examples (and *We **must** do homework*) are completely equivalent (but apart from the possible *semantic* difference given below, note that "required" is more "formal").

But in *some* contexts, the "required" version strongly implies *someone or something **else*** is imposing the requirement on the subject. Thus ***I must / have to eat*** probably reflects an *internal* compulsion to eat (I'm really hungry, and/or I'll starve if I don't eat). But ***I am required to eat*** is more likely if I'm being forced to eat unwillingly (an anorexic under doctor's orders, perhaps).

Comment: I agree, in most contexts they are equivalent. One is more formal (as in what a school would write) and the other is less formal (what a student might actually say). But the meaning is the same.

Comment: @Lambie: Good point. I'll edit to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. If your home is at the top of a hill, you will **have** to climb the hill to get home, but you are not **required** to climb the hill (unless someone tells you to do so). However, you could say that necessity requires you to climb the hill. Usually, if you are required to do something, it is to keep someone else happy.